# How to control percent_pattern in the R Crosstable package?

Tags: r, crosstable

When using Crosstable in RStudio, I don't want to include a percent result alongside my figures in the total column. I can control the appearance of percentages within the body of my table using percent_pattern = {n}, however this does not remove percentages from my results column.

This:

```
library(crosstable)
crosstable(mtcars2, am, by=vs, total="both", percent_pattern = "{n}") %>% 
  as_flextable(keep_id=TRUE)
```

Produces this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAYnS.png)

The package news explains the following:
*percent_pattern can now be a list of characters with names body, total_row, total_col, and total_all to also control the pattern in other parts of the crosstable than the body.*

Based on this I have used the code below, however the percentages remain.

```
crosstable(mtcars2, am, by=vs, total="both", percent_pattern = list(total_all = "{n}")) %>% 
  as_flextable(keep_id=TRUE)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [in the vignette](https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/articles/percent_pattern.html#proportions-in-totals), the proper way to change `percent_pattern` in all the different parts of a `crosstable` is the following:

```
pp_n = list(body="{n}", total_row="{n}", total_col="{n}", total_all="{n}")
crosstable(mtcars2, cyl, by=vs, total=TRUE, 
           percent_pattern=pp_n) %>% 
  as_flextable()
```

If you want this behavior for all your crosstable, you can change the default pattern through options like this:

```
crosstable_options(percent_pattern=pp_n)
```

**EDIT:** Your second code is definitely a bug (https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable/issues/52), it will be corrected in the next version (which will be published this century for sure).

Comment: Dan - thanks for the reply, not quite sure how I missed that in the vignette! At least I inadvertently spotted a bug. Great package btw - finding it very useful.